# Check condition on curl response code and response body

Tags: linux, bash, unix, curl

I want to check the condition on curl response code and response body. The response body contain the enum(Success or Failure) I have to check condition on that too.

So basically, I will the send the request using CURL , if there are error responses I will print error, if not  I will check the condition on the response body's enum for success or failure, if failure I will print error.

I am facing the problem in extracting response code and body from the response, and parsing them. Other answers only shows how to extract response code separately. I want to work with them at the same time and not sent separate request for both. I am thinking of extracting the code and body in one variable then parsing them. Code examples would help

```
status_code=$(curl localhost:9090/employee/get/1 -I -w "%{http_code}\n")
```

Thanks

Comment: Shos us **your code**

Comment: @GillesQuenot I haven't written much code yet, this will be hardly 5 to 6 lines code. But I have posted the code for extracting the status code .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(curl localhost:9090/employee/get/1 -I -w "%{http_code}\n")
status_code=$(awk 'END{print}' <<< "$data")

case "$status_code" in
    4*|5*)
        echo "ERR $status_code" >&2 
    ;;
    2*|3*)
        echo "OK $status_code"
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Not implemented ERR $status_code" >&2
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: I guess this is the only way to fetch response code and body in the same variable. After that we can do stream editing on that variable to fetch them separately. Thanks